# How to simulate event of barcode scanning

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cypress

I have to write automation tests for an application that listens to events of a USB barcode scanner, and does some functionality on the event of a scan. The application uses [react-barcode-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-barcode-reader). I want to simulate a scan event (i.e. triggering the functionality without physical scanner).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Did U search how to mock event on node ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your code

Comment: A typical scanner works just like a keyboard.  After the scanner has completed it's scan, the key that is returned is usually the enter key.  The keys value is 13, so what I do is have an onkeypressed function as an attribute to my input tag and if the key is 13 I return the value from the input.  Therefore you can just have an input tag that is of type ```text``` and hit the enter key after you've put in the barcode that you want.

Comment: @Michael is correct, if you look at the source for this component, in `componentDidMount()` it listens to the keypress event - however, two potential problems: 1) there's a scanner detection routine that might stop things working if you have no scanner, & 2)  Cypress would send keys via the `.type('my-text-for-testing')` command, but it needs an input control of some kind to target and the component has none, so you will need to look at the DOM and determine which element receives the keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. 
Here is the cypress code that worked for me:

```
   cy.get('body').type("MY BARCODE").trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 13, which: 13 })
```

This code creates an event of scan. 
Thanks!!!